# How to return multiple image elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to find a way to return multiple images from a function. In the example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-jennings-fcghy
you can see that the first function can return a single image, but i cannot figure out how to properly return multiple images. i tried concatinating the  elements, but that only rendered the string and not the image.
Please excuse the messy code.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Note that you can create a **runnable** [mcve] here on-site using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to return multiple image elements in React?

By returning an array of elements. For instance:

```
return [
    <img src="a.png"/>,
    <img src="b.png"/>,
    <img src="c.png"/>,
];
```

That works as the return value of a reusable function, and also as the return value of a functional component or a class component's `render`.